# Pegar resposta da callback

Tags: javascript, callback

Como pego/utilizo a resposta dessa callback aqui?

```
const arr = ["Lucas"];

function minhaCall(sobrenome, indice) {
    return indice + 1 + ") " + sobrenome + " de Carvalho";
}

arr.forEach(minhaCall)
```

Por exemplo, eu não posso dar um `console.log(arr.forEach(minhaCall))`

como eu utilizaria o retorno dessa função?

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem o que você quis dizer, mas você pode por o `console.log` no lugar do `return`.

Comment: Sim, Caique, mas ai não adiantaria pra mim. Por exemplo, o console.log eu posso usar apenas no contexto de console, mas se eu quisesse usar esse dado em outro lugar? Desculpa se está meio confuso.

Comment: Parece mais que você quer fazer um `map` do *array* do que um `forEach`.

Comment: Relaxa, acho que entendi agora, acredito que `forEach` não seja a melhor forma para isso, mas  primeira solução que me veio a cabeça seria armazenar/incrementar em uma variável os retornos.

Comment: Melhor você falar o que você quer realmente fazer ao invés de imaginar uma solução e tentar entendê-la. O que você tem de entrada e o que espera de saída?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente o que você quer é gerar um novo *array* de *strings* a partir do original. Se for o caso, isso é feito com o `Array.map`, não o `Array.forEach`.

Recomendo ler a documentação de cada para mais detalhes:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Assim, ficaria:

```js
const arr = ["Lucas"];

function minhaCall(sobrenome, indice) {
    return indice + 1 + ") " + sobrenome + " de Carvalho";
}

console.log(arr.map(minhaCall));
```

Ou de forma simplificada:

```js
const arr = ["Lucas"];
const novoArr = arr.map((nome, i) => `${i+1}) ${nome} de Carvalho`);

console.log(novoArr);
```

Answer (score -2):

Sua pergunta não ficou clara, mas acredito que esteja tentando fazer algo deste tipo:

```
const arr = ['Lucas']

const minhaCall = (sobrenome, indice) => `${indice + 1}) ${sobrenome} de Carvalho`

arr.map((nome, i) => {
    console.log(minhaCall(nome, i))
})
```

Comment: Nesse caso a solução seria o `forEach` mesmo, não o `map`.